# Video play/stop button WAI-ARIA accessibility advice?

Tags: html, accessibility, media-player, wai-aria

I have in my page "play/Stop Button Element". The button is changed to "play" or "stop" when it's pressed.

Do I need to add a WAI-ARIA label to it when it's in play or stop mode? Or just change the title of the button?

```
<button title="stop video" class="BtnStyle Video Stop">Stop icon</button>
<button title="play video" class="BtnStyle Video play">Play icon</button>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code so I'm sure I answer this correctly?

Comment: i add the html to the question above, the button is change on click to play and on click to stop... do i need some more attribute for accessibility ?

Comment: Please add the icon HTML so I know how you are inserting it.  The `title` attribute should never be used as a sufficient label, so the icon is what needs to be labeled.

Comment: i just wanted to know if i need some aria label like "aria-live="polite" or something like that ? because the button is changed to another button on press

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a toggle button. To make an accessible toggle button you need to add `aria-pressed="true/false"`. Based on wheter it's playing or not aria-pressed is true or false. You can read more here: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/button/button.html

Answer (score 0):

Technically, according to WCAG, you don't have to notify the user of the change in the label.  Some might argue that dynamic content or dynamic changes to labels falls under [WCAG 4.1.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#status-messages) but that checkpoint is for "[status messages](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/status-messages.html#dfn-status-message)", which says that the dynamic content must provide information to the user on one of the following:

- the success or results of an action
- the waiting state of an application
- the progress of a process
- the existence of errors

Changing "play" to "pause" and vice versa doesn't fall under one of those categories.

However, even though WCAG does not *require* it, that doesn't mean you shouldn't try to notify the user somehow if it's appropriate.  Toggling the label of a button is not uncommon, especially in this video or audio case.

After selecting the "play" button, presumably they'll hear audio starting.  If you *also* announce that a label changed, it might interfere with the audio that's playing and could be a *worse* experience.  So this really comes down to a usability issue that might require some usability tests (some that announce the change and some that don't.).

Many screen reader users navigate the entire page to get a mental image of the layout of the page.  They'll navigate through all the video/audio buttons and hear "play" but not a "pause" button.  Some might logically conclude that there isn't a pause button because nothing is playing.  (The pause button might be visible but inactive, although a screen reader user can navigate to inactive elements and could know they're there.)  Then when they play, they might navigate around and find that there's now a pause button but no play button.  It's a bit of a stretch because not all users are technically savvy and would figure this out.  Again, it comes down to some usability tests.